# Raster calculation qgis >=

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

So I have been trying to figure this one out for ages but I just can't seem to do it.

I have 2 rasters. One representing terrain and the other representing an interpolated surface which is beneath the ground.

The interpolated layer is greater than ground level in some places, which in reality is impossible. I need to make the interpolated layer equal to the ground surface layer where it has a greater elevation than the ground surface.

It looks like this in profile view

[image]

How can I do this..?

Comment: Are you creating the interpolated surface below ground level?  If so, what are your methods?

Comment: I use Grid(Interpolation) to turn point data into a rasterized surface

Comment: Try SAGA raster calculator. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110248/saga-raster-calculator-ifelse-command-syntax-problem

Comment: This means that the source data you're using for interpolation has wrong values in some places. It is quite possible that it is not limited to the areas where the result looks to be above ground. You are only able to see the error when the values are above ground. If that is the case, I would question the validity of this source data.

Comment: Hi Techie_Gus. I am not worried about the validity of the data, the ground surface having been modified, i.e cut whereas the modelled below ground surface follows the natural contours. Cheers